# Adding percentage related validations to html input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small page that lets me add stocks to my portfolio by clicking on "Add Stock" button, check the image below for reference.

[image]

Clicking on "Add Stock" button pops up a modal box, that lists stocks that I can add to my portfolio.

[image]

I can allocate stock (in percentage) by clicking on the "Allocate" button. This updates my portfolio table. I want to add the following validations here.

1. Users should not be allowed to give non-numeric value in the above input box.
2. Value should always be in a range of 0 to 100. Fractions are allowed.
3. Sum of percentages of all stocks in my portfolio should never be more than 100%.

Please note that I can update the stock percentage from the portfolio table as well.

[image]

I can delete the record too.

[image]

On clicking "Update" button I update portfolio in the backend, I would want to add validations to happen here as well, i.e. on button click event before firing Ajax call.

CodePen Link with complete working code: https://codepen.io/agrawalo/pen/rNBGyww

Corresponding JS code:

```
function insertRow(code, name, price, diff){

    let percentage = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_"+code).value);
  innerHTML = '<td class="pt-3-half" >'+ code +'</td>' +
                  '<td class="pt-3-half" >'+name.replace(/_/g, ' ') +'</td>' +
                  '<td class="pt-3-half" >'+price+'</td>'
  innerHTML += diff >=0 ? '<td class="pt-3-half" style="color:#00c851" ><b>'+diff+'</b></td>' : '<td class="pt-3-half" style="color:red"><b>'+diff+'</b></td>'
  innerHTML +=  '<td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">'+percentage +'</td>'
  innerHTML +=  '<td>' +
                          '<a onclick=removeRow(this)>' +
                                   '<i class="fa fa-times" onmouseover="this.style.color=\'tomato\'" onmouseout="this.style.color=\'grey\'" aria-hidden="true" style="color: grey;"></i>' +
                          '</a>' +
                        '</td>';
  $('#row_'+code).remove();
  $("#table-body").append('<tr id="row_'+code+'">'+innerHTML+'</tr>');
}
```

I want a very intuitive way of adding these validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the first thing with giving your element a type like this:

```
<input type="number" value="someValue" >
```

for second one you can add an if in your javascript file like this:

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
  let value = event.target.value
  if(value < 100){
    /* do your job with the correct answer */
  }else {
    document.getElementById("input id").classList.add("Error class in css")
  }
}
```

above function goes to onChange attribute of your input element.

and for third one you can do it with if too.